# cant sudo apt update due to a connection failure

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, connection

```
Cannot initiate the connection to download.opensuse.org:80 (2001:67c:2178:8::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to download.opensuse.org:80 (195.135.221.134), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/hardware:/razer/xUbuntu_22.04/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to download.opensuse.org:80 (2001:67c:2178:8::13). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to download.opensuse.org:80 (195.135.221.134), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am unsure of what the problem is or how to fix it.
This occurs when trying to either when I "sudo apt --fix-missing update" or "sudo apt update"

For context, I think the Razer it's trying to fetch is from RazerGenie

Comment: You have to ask Opensuse support, why their server is unavailable.

Comment: OpenSUSE's download page is down (major outage), see https://status.opensuse.org/

Answer (score 0):

From the first line, the error indicates a mirror that is down or unavailable.  Generally, this means that some repositories activated don’t exist anymore, at least on the mirror we are using. This error will be gone once the mirror is back online.reference [Some index files failed to download: Ubuntu – How to fix](https://bobcares.com/blog/some-index-files-failed-to-download/)

Comment: Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from https://bobcares.com/blog/some-index-files-failed-to-download. You're using someone else's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on Ask Ubuntu. Remember to **always** add prominent attribution when using other sources. Thanks!

Comment: ok so sorry i edited my answer

Comment: @MartinThornton While this answer is merely a guess and limited in its view as the reason might be any of other reasons as well e.g. (Network proxy/caching, APT proxy, notwork  latency, firewalls, DNS resolution, IPv6 issues on either sides ... etc.) to name but a few given the limited information in the question ... However, I don't see anything unique(*technically*) in it that needs to or even can be copied from elsewhere ... It's not even a well formed paragraph ... If I had to throw a guess, then I would safely assume it can't be plagiarism :-)

Comment: @Raffa thanks for your comment but in reality i copied it and edited again to mentioning the reference

Comment: LOL :-D ... Thanks "'طلعت" for your honesty ... I however still wonder how @MartinThornton could spot that in an answer that is almost a single general statement ... Martin, you are a very talented man ... Keep up the good investigative work .. I will take your word for it from now on :-)

Comment: @Raffa There was one other answer that was deleted before I could comment on it, that was a mix of two obviously different writing styles and had misunderstood the question.

Comment: @MartinThornton Oh yes I can see that one ... It's a [Stylometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry) thing then ... Still I'm amazed at such a talent ... Impressive indeed :-)